# UnsatisfiableError while installing Spyder

Tags: 16.04, python, spyder

I am new to Ubuntu and I was trying to install Spyder on my ubuntu 16.04 and I am getting this error:

```
 UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
 conflict:
   - spyder 3.1.4*
   - spyder-app -> spyder 2.3.4 Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How do I resolve this? I really don't understand this.

The command I am using is:

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder=3.1.4
```

Comment: What commands were you using to install Spyder? Do you have Anaconda installed too?

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3667

Comment: @edwinksl I do have anaconda installed and I have edited the question a little.